# Error in passing a constant argument to mapply() function

Tags: r, mapply

I have created a function that run `FastICA` on a dataset with different number of components and it returns ICA signals (S matrix) but in a long format.

```
compute_ICA <- function(r)
  
{
   res_ICA <- fastICA(df, r, alg.typ = "parallel", fun = "logcosh", alpha = 1,
             method = "R", row.norm = FALSE, maxit = 200,
             tol = 0.0000001, verbose = FALSE)
   df_long<-reshape2::melt(as.data.frame(res_ICA$S))
   return(df_long)
}
```

Now I want to repeat this function 100 times for one specific r (number of components) and keep track of the iteration number.
So I tried this :

```
iterate_ICA <- function(r,t)
{for (i in r)
{
  res<-mapply(compute_ICA, t, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  res_unzip<-do.call(rbind, res)
  res_unzip$iteration <- i
  return(res_unzip)
}
  }
```

But when I try applying the `iterate_ICA()` function like this I get this error:

```
res_zip<-mapply(iterate_ICA, 1:100, 3, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

```
Error in dots[[1L]][[1L]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error, however, I think you misunderstood what
`mapply` does.

When you apply `mapply` to a function `FUN`, with arguments that are
lists or vectors (consider that R basic types like numbers or characters are always vectors), the function `FUN` is called iteratively on the first element of all the arguments, then on the second, etc. Arguments are recycled if necessary.

For instance:

```r
fn <- function(num, let) {
  data.frame(num = num, let = let)
}

mapply(FUN = fn, 1:5, letters[1:5], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

##> [[1]]
##>   num let
##> 1   1   a
##> 
##> [[2]]
##>   num let
##> 1   2   b
##> 
##> [[3]]
##>   num let
##> 1   3   c
##> 
##> [[4]]
##>   num let
##> 1   4   d
##> 
##> [[5]]
##>   num let
##> 1   5   e
```

To comply with the expected behavior you described, the `iterate_ICA`
function should read like this:

```r
iterate_ICA<-function(r,t) {
  res <-  compute_ICA(t)
  return(cbind(res, iteration = r))
}
```

Then you iterate it using `mapply`:

```r
res <- mapply(iterate_ICA, 1:100, 3, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Finally, you merge all the replicates:

```r
res_unzip <- do.call(rbind, res)
```